# OpenMobileAPI, GetData command returns shown values without PIN

Tags: android, open-mobile-api

I'm using `seek-for-android` to connect to the `SecureElement` on the `SIM card`.

I'm able to get the data e.g. card number, cvc, ..,  using a `Get Data` command, for example the card number is as follow `1111 **** **** 1111` **WITH THE ACTUAL * CHARS**.

now I want to get the full number so I run a `Verify Pin` **AND** a `Get Data` command, the data is shown correctly like `1111 1111 1111 1111`,

**PROBLEM**: now every time I try the `Get Data` command, it return a clear (shown) card number like `1111 1111 1111 1111` even when I don't send a `Verify Pin` command, FYI I'm closing the channel after every command so that's obviously not it.

**NOTE**: when I send an incorrect PIN it then starts returning me a hidden card number

any suggestions? thank you !!

Comment: seek opens a logical channel (assuming that you did not somehow bypass that logical channel concept on your device) to the applet on the card, so it performs a fresh selection of the applet upon opening a channel. Therefore, the applet seems to keep its authentication state beyond selection cycles, which is odd but if that's the way that applet works, then I guess there is not much you could do about it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although I found a way to doing that, it's a ResetParams command that seems to reset everything, so when I request the data it is not shown.